Trying to apply mask to an image with similar dimension yet fails
Trying to implement mask in form of array from torch.Tensordata type, with this code
from transformers import OneFormerProcessor, OneFormerForUniversalSegmentation, SegformerImageProcessor, SegformerForSemanticSegmentation

from PIL import Image
import requests
import cv2
    
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# importing image to use 
image = Image.open("D:\img_1.jpg")   


# Create mask from a pretrained model   
# Loading a single model for all three tasks
processor_shilab = OneFormerProcessor.from_pretrained("shi-labs/oneformer_ade20k_swin_large")

model_shilab = OneFormerForUniversalSegmentation.from_pretrained("shi-labs/oneformer_ade20k_swin_large")
        
panoptic_inputs = processor_shilab(images=image, task_inputs=["panoptic"], return_tensors="pt")

panoptic_outputs = model_shilab(**panoptic_inputs)

#predicted_panoptic_map in torch.Tensor type
predicted_panoptic_map = processor_shilab.post_process_panoptic_segmentation(panoptic_outputs, target_sizes=[image.size[::-1]])[0]["segmentation"]

#color array
color = np.array([0, 255, 0], dtype="uint8")
    
masked_image = np.where(predicted_panoptic_map, image)
    

Then has this error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[37], line 3
      1 color = np.array([0, 255, 0], dtype="uint8")
----> 3 masked_image = np.where(predicted_panoptic_map, color, grey)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1080,1080) (3,) (1080, 1080, 3)

before it has different dimension with the image that is (1080, 1080, 3) so I immediately make it grayscale to make it (1080, 1080) similar to the mask
But after reduce the dimension, I received this error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[37], line 3
      1 color = np.array([0, 255, 0], dtype="uint8")
----> 3 masked_image = np.where(predicted_panoptic_map, color, grey)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1080,1080) (3,) (1080,1080)

Removing the color array gives me
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[38], line 3
      1 color = np.array([0, 255, 0], dtype="uint8")
----> 3 masked_image = np.where(predicted_panoptic_map, grey)

ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given

The dimensions are the same, the mask is generated from the said image, what else did I missed?
Note the mask is already in color? something like this
[![plotted-mask with matplotlib][1]][1]
Edit 4: The mask isn't in color, I guess it's from matplotlib
Edit 5: editing only for posterity, will read the numpy docs as suggested

In the first error case you need a (1080,1080,1) array to broadcast all 3 arguments,

Mask have no color, by definition. They usually come in 2 kinds, depending on what produce them (there is no general rule): either a H×W image of booleans, or, if there are more than 1 binary classification, a collection of K H×W array of booleans (or a K×W×H array of booleans, or a W×H×K array of booleans), K being the number of classes. Or (for example cv2.connectedComponents, and I bet your code), a H×W array of ints, with a class number in each pixel. Second is more compact, but can represent only mutually exclusive classes (unless a variant where classes are power of 2, ored, is used)

But, point is, mask don't have colors. Now, your code is way to partial and we can't reproduce anything, for us to be able to tell you more. You didn't even say which line of code produce an error, what are the shape of the arguments, what you call "removing color array", etc.

@chrslg I literally define an array called color there what else should I add for reproducibility? I also define the mask data shape. You can just add all the codes I wrote there and try running it on your notebook. The imports? fine.

@hpaulj that's the picture (img, the one on the most right side of the parameters) right? I add two 1080 x 1080 x 1 array here what's going on?

I swear I am unable to understand what is the code you run on which data to cause the error you have. I have no idea what you call "when I remove color" (remove color from what? from where? All we have is an array color totally unrelated to any other line of codes. You don't claim that the simple fact of not defining this array change the result of totally unrelated code? That would be a mystery indeed). And, yes, you must includes import in a [mre]. And in correct order, not separately to shut up a grumpy commenter. But that was not the most important part.

The important part is that we should be able to reproduce your error by a simple copy&paste of provided code. We can't. That being said, I am not interested in fights, so good luck. Some smarter people than I am might guess what the problem is.

masked_image = np.where(predicted_panoptic_map[:,:,None], color, image) might work.

My guess is the mask needs an extra dimension to broadcast with the color and image arrays.  READ more numpy basics!  The errors are consistent with problems in a where function.

@chrslg, the errors look like a problem with arguments of a where. He's trying to change the color of selected pixels.  The image is 3d, the mask is 2d, just the pixels. A simple dimensional change of the mask should be enough to make the broadcasting work.

The where line does not use the color variable.  I can guess where it occurred when you got the first error. But your editing is sloppy.  When asking about errors, show the WHOLE error message.
